# How can I get back my Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, data-recovery, windows-10

My first OS was Windows 10. Then I install ubuntu 16.04. But though the installation finished, the grub menu didn't come out. Then I format that free space partition and reinstall again. Also went into the same old issue. Then I install third time, ''Install alongside with Windows'' step was not there anymore. Then I install ubuntu straight. Then, after restarting, no boot option comes out and then automatically login into ubuntu straight.
I see my Windows 10 system files inside there.
Is it overwrite on my OS or how can I get back my Windows 10. Now I'm on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You mean to say Grub does not have a Windows loader ?

Comment: The windows installation was deleted andiy's gonna be hard to recover....make space and install windows afresh.

Answer (score 0):

Well You Will Need A Windows 10 ISO And A Usb With Minimum 4GB Or Longer

With A Program Called:Rufus

1.Download The Windows 10 ISO

2.Download Rofus https://rufus.akeo.ie/

3.Put Your Usb

4.Go In A Disk And Select The Windows 10 ISO

5.Start it. Wait Until Its Finished

6.Reboot Your Laptop

7.Start Windows 10 Installation

I Hope You Fix This Soon

Comment: thanks a lir for answering for me. but you mean I'm going to reinstall windows10again?

Comment: my system files are still inside there. Do I still have chance to call back windows 10?

Comment: Yes Of Course!!

Comment: ''sudo update-grub''

Comment: Now solved by this command.

Comment: Know Do That I Was Showing